# I have a range in an excel document which I need to extract into a listbox in Visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range in an excel document which I need to extract into a listbox. I can do this through .txt file, but really would prefer to source the information from excel. How?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and so far my code is:

```
Public class1 Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim objXLApp As Excel.Application
Dim intLoopCounter As Integer

objXLApp = New Excel.Application

With objXLApp
    .Workbooks.Open("C:\report.xls")
    .Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Select()

    For intLoopCounter = 1 To CInt(.ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
        List1.AddItem.Range("A" & intLoopCounter)
    Next intLoopCounter

    .Workbooks(1).Close(False)
    .Quit()
End With

objXLApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I build this program I get two errors;

1. statement is not valid in namespace
2. end of statement expected (I did put end class but it adds more couple of errors")

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.NET? Your tags and text seem to not be in agreement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really do VB, but I think you should break the binding out of the loop with something like:

```
var data = .ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A"&.ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Value2

List1.DataSource = data
List1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks Malk, but why is it showing me the error that excel.application is not a valid namespace? is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: @Malk these are not available methods or properties in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You could try (assuming you want the whole `Range` object to be bound to the list and not just the displayed value.

```
For intLoopCounter = 1 To CInt(.ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
    List1.AddItem .ActiveSheet.Range("A" & intLoopCounter)
Next intLoopCounter
```

**Edit:**

Also you should use `Set objXLApp = New Excel.Application`. You're missing the `set` keyword.

This is also not how you declare classes in VBA. You make a new class like you make a new module. The class is named in the properties pane.

Also this is not how events are handled in VBA. If you want to handle the `button click` event of `Button1` then the event handler must look like

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

End Sub
```

It must have the same name as the object and the name of the event being handled. It also must be on the code page for the user form and has no parameters. VBA is really lacking in this regard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim XLApp As Object, xlBook As Object, xlSheet As Object
XLApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
xlBook = XLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\report.xls")
xlSheet = XLApp.Worksheets(1) ' Activate first sheet
XLApp.Visible = True
xlSheet.Cells(2, 3) = "This is cell C2"
XLApp.Quit()
        xlSheet = Nothing
        xlBook = Nothing
        XLApp = Nothing



    End Sub
End Class

Comment: The code i posted above works great only problem now is that it does not open the excel in VB instead it opens excel file itself?

Comment: That is pretty tough to read...you should edit your question if you want to paste a block of code like that.